# Using short circuit evaluation to define variable

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables, short-circuiting

Why do you have to use the var keyword when defining a variable using short circuit evaluation?

This works...

```
var sum=sum||5;
console.log(sum); //shows 5;
```

This does not work...

```
sum=sum||5;
console.log(sum); //error sum is not defined;
```

Shouldn't the second example just make sum===5 but at the global scope and not the local?

Answer (score 1):

What happens internally when you do `var sum=sum||5;` is this:

- variable `sum` is defined, it's created,
- variable `sum` is assigned an `undefined` value
- variable `sum` is assigned the result of `sum || 5`, which is like saying `undefined || 5`, which is `5`

When you simply do `sum = sum||5` the first and second steps from above do not happen, so in the third step you are short-circuiting something that does not exist *at all* with the value `5`, and that's why you get that error.

In order to understand that better, do this: Open up your browser's console and simply write `sum`. You will get an error because `sum` does not exist. Now, do `sum = ''`. What happened here is that a variable `sum` was defined/created, **as if you had done `var sum`**, it now exists, and it was assigned the value `''`.

The essence of the above, which you should understand, is that there is a difference between *short-circuiting the value `undefined` with the value `5`* and *short-circuiting something that does not exist with value `5`*